# UICollectionView is very slow when inserting or deleting many items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to insert and delete a large amount of items (say, 20,000) from a collection view, and the operation takes a very long time.

The test fixture I created is composed of the following:

- `UICollectionView` with no configuration besides a data source.
- Default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
- Data source that returns either 10K or 30K items depending on a `BOOL` variable.
- Button to toggle that variable. When set to `YES`, 20K items are being added to the data source (just by changing `numberOfItemsInSection:`) and `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` with 20K items. When set to `NO`, `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:` is called with 20K items.
- Cell configuration in the data source does nothing besides dequeuing a default `UICollectionViewCell` and returning it.

Running this on simulator, which should be faster than any device, yields the following timings:

- Insertion of 20K items: 220ms.
- Deletion of the same 20K items: 1100ms.

This is, by all means, horribly slow, especially when performed on the main thread.

Here's a screenshot from instruments, showing the hotspots in UICollectionView's internal implementation (specifically, `_computeItemUpdates`):

[image: Instruments]

I've noticed that the use of `reloadData` instead of inserting or updating the items is way faster (~20ms), probably because no animations are triggered so there's no need to compute the position of each item and section for animation purposes.

Any ideas on how to overcome this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` and `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:` instead of `reloadData`?

Comment: `reloadData` resets all the state in the view controller such as scroll position and index path of selected items.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using performBatchUpdates:completion: ?

Comment: `performBatchUpdates:completion:` doesn't affect the performance (I've tested it), it only kicks in when executing multiple updates in a batch.

Comment: If insertItemsAtIndexPaths: is triggering UI updates, it might be worth reworking the insert to _do_ multiple inserts as a batch, since that is specifically documented to do one animation update for the batch.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work - the pending item updates are being queued until the block finishes executing, and the update takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Any progress with this problem? I'm also having similar problems when working with 10k+ items collection. I'm using my own layout, but the Instruments screenshot looks about the same in my case :-(

Answer (score 0):

Expand `_computeItemUpdates`.  If anything it's calling is yours, then yes you can.

An example would be if you are using a custom layout, you could ask it to calculate the new positions on a background thread and then call insert/delete when that operation finishes.

You could also be smart about it and only call insert/delete for ranges that are currently visible, then after the rearrange animation finishes you could `reloadData` and it shouldn't look too different from a users perspective.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I'm currently using a bare-naked flow layout (tried it with a `UICollectionViewLayout` that returns a very simple layout as well with similar results). `reloadData` has the problem of losing the current state of the collection view, which needs to be restored. And nothing besides `UIKit` under `_computeItemUpdates`.

Comment: @StatusReport `reloadData` maintains scroll position.  I don't know what more you want.  And if you're using a basic flow layout then you need to follow the other part of my answer and see if any of that 69% is in your code.  If it's not, then you can't optimize any further while still using a basic flow layout.

Comment: you're right about the scrolling position, but I still lose the selected items, so I'd need to calculate the new indices of the currently selected items based on the update (they can be deleted, modified or items may have been inserted before them). Custom layout won't help here since, as I said, my code is not the hotspot, and I'm using a very basic layout.