# How can I insert section/items into a UICollectionView rapidly without blocking the main thread/UI?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, realm, grand-central-dispatch

I have a process that runs in the background that is adding a lot of `Realm` records for a couple minutes.  I also have a `UICollectionView` which has a datasource hooked up to a `List` of those Realm records.  I have a Realm notification hooked up to call `insertItems(at:)` when new records are added.

The problem is that since there are so many insertions back-to-back, the main thread is almost always waiting on the `insertItems(at:)` call to finish.  Therefore, the app is *completely* unresponsive until the insertions finish.

First, it seems strange to me that `insertItems(at:)` is taking so long, since only maybe the initial 0.05% of the records are even visible, so I would have thought that UIKit would be optimized to not do a bunch of work for cells off-screen.  It's calling `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` for every cell, even when they're off screen.  I'm surprised that UIKit bothers to call this delegate method on cells which are not on screen or even close to being on screen. The only reason I can think of needing to know the size of cells so far down below the currently visible cells is so that the scroll indicator can be sized and animated more accurately.

Since apparently UICollectionView is doing work for every IndexPath insertion even when not necessary (I'm hoping I'm wrong), I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion for how to structure it such that the records can still be added as quickly as possible while not blocking the UI.  Maybe there's a way to structure this differently with GCD or something?

Comment: What sort of layout are you using? If it's a flow layout, have you set the `estimatedItemSize` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617709-estimateditemsize ?

Comment: Yea, that works when there's only 1 section.  However, if I use multiple sections, it's still the same problem.  I could convert to using just 1 section, but that leads to me having to define my own layout.

Comment: Actually it makes it worse, when you scroll it starts to mess up the size of cells when they shouldn't just be estimates.

Comment: Setting `estimatedItemSize` says nothing about the size the cells will be on screen, merely that the layout shouldn't worry about figuring out what they are until then. But it's a layout-side hack: the collection view still asks the layout for the size of all cells, it just creatively provides potentially misleading information until the last minute. I think Apple's problem is that the collection view technically offers random access via setting `contentOffset` which makes it hard to build out the sizes as you go. None of which is useful, I think. I'll try to think of something more helpful.

Comment: Did you try to profile it in Instruments? see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216412/uicollectionview-is-very-slow-when-inserting-or-deleting-many-items